# Why am I getting "algorithm did not converge" and "fitted prob numerically 0 or 1" warnings with glm?

Tags: r, statistics, r-zelig

So this is a very simple question, just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm running a logit using the glm function, but keep getting warning messages relating to the independent variable. They're stored as factors and I've changed them to numeric but had no luck. I also coded them to 0/1 but that did not work either.

Please help!

```
> mod2 <- glm(winorlose1 ~ bid1, family="binomial")
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

I also tried it in Zelig, but similar error:

```
> mod2 = zelig(factor(winorlose1) ~ bid1, data=dat, model="logit")
How to cite this model in Zelig:
Kosuke Imai, Gary King, and Oliva Lau. 2008. "logit: Logistic Regression for Dichotomous Dependent Variables" in Kosuke Imai, Gary King, and Olivia Lau, "Zelig: Everyone's Statistical Software," http://gking.harvard.edu/zelig
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

EDIT:

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   3493 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ winorlose1: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ bid1      : int  700 300 700 300 500 300 300 700 300 300 ...
 $ home      : int  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:63021] 3494 3495 3496 3497 3498 3499 3500 3501 3502 3503 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:63021] "3494" "3495" "3496" "3497" ...
```

Comment: This will be impossible to answer without some detailed information about your data. `str(dat)` for instance. Also, those are warnings, not errors. There's a big difference.

Comment: I just wanted to note that there is a `glm2` package which claims to achieve convergence where `glm` does not. I don't know if this has to do with the problem here or not. See http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Marschner.pdf

Comment: As it seems that you're working with categorical data, I'd consider casting your integer variables as factors. dat$home <- as.factor(dat$home)

Comment: some more information [on http://stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: Added some possible solutions, with reference to concrete packages you could try...

Answer (score 47):

If you look at `?glm` (or even do a Google search for your second warning message) you may stumble across this from the documentation:

> For the background to warning messages about ‘fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred’ for binomial GLMs, see Venables & Ripley (2002, pp. 197–8).

Now, not everyone has that book. But assuming it's kosher for me to do this, here's the relevant passage:

> There is one fairly common circumstance in which both convergence
>   problems and the Hauck-Donner phenomenon can occur. This is when the
>   fitted probabilities are extremely close to zero or one. Consider a
>   medical diagnosis problem with thousands of cases and around 50 binary
>   explanatory variable (which may arise from coding fewer categorical
>   variables); one of these indicators is rarely true but always
>   indicates that the disease is present. Then the fitted probabilities
>   of cases with that indicator should be one, which can only be achieved
>   by taking β<sub>i</sub> = ∞. The result from `glm` will be
>   warnings and an estimated coefficient of around +/- 10. There has been
>   fairly extensive discussion of this in the statistical literature,
>   usually claiming non-existence of maximum likelihood estimates; see
>   Sautner and Duffy (1989, p. 234).

One of the authors of this book commented in somewhat more detail [here](http://math.yorku.ca/Who/Faculty/Monette/S-news/0027.html). So the lesson here is to look carefully at one of the levels of your predictor. (And Google the warning message!)

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Just to add: it's good to look at the model, the model diagnostics, and sometimes a different model.  For instance, try a classification tree.  This may tell you that either (a) you have an excellent predictor (good thing), or (b) you have some sampling problems (bad thing).

Comment: Does this answer address only the 2nd warning from the OP's question?  I found at http://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/warning-message-glm-fit-algorithm-did-not-converge/5299 the suggestion to adjust the parameter `maxit` (which is not listed in the documentation for `glm`, but is passed as part of the `control` parameter to `glm.fit` and then to `glm.control`), and that seems to have resolved the 1st warning `1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge` for me.

Comment: I found your answer very useful joran, but I still don't understand how to solve the problem based on your answer. My understanding (based on the quote in your answer) is that: one of the levels of one of my predictor variables is rarely true but always indicates that the the out come variable is either 0 or 1. Firstly, surely any decent statistical method should be able to deal with this? Secondly, how do I find the predictor variable, and once I do find it what do I do with it?

Comment: @par An algorithmic approach to "solving" this problem is often to employ some form of regularization. But it is also wise to reconsider your choices of covariates in the context of your model, and how meaningful they might be. As the quote indicates, you can often spot the problem variable by looking for a coefficient of +/- 10.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably due to complete separation, i.e. one group being entirely composed of 0s or 1s.

There are several options to deal with this:

(a) Use Firth's penalized likelihood method, as implemented in the packages [logistf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/index.html), [brglm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brglm/index.html) or [brglm2](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brglm2/versions/0.9.2) in R. This uses the method proposed in Firth (1993), "Bias reduction of maximum likelihood estimates", *Biometrika*, **80**,1.; which removes the first-order bias from maximum likelihood estimates.

(b) By using median-unbiased estimates in exact conditional logistic regression. Package [elrm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elrm/index.html) or [logistiX](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistiX/index.html) in R can do this.

(c) Use LASSO or elastic net regularized logistic regression, e.g. using the [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) package in R.

(d) Go Bayesian, cf. the paper [Gelman et al (2008), "A weakly informative default prior distribution for logistic & other regression models", *Ann. Appl. Stat.*, **2**, 4](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1231424214), e.g. using the [brms](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.20.4) package or by using function [bayesglm](https://rdrr.io/cran/arm/man/bayesglm.html) in the arm package.

(e) Use a hidden logistic regression model, as described in Rousseeuw & Christmann (2003),"Robustness against separation and outliers in logistic regression", *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, **43**, 3, and implemented in the R package [hlr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hlr/index.html).

You need to recode your factor as a factor first though using `dat$bid1 = as.factor(dat$bid1)`)

Solutions to this problem are also discussed here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/logistic-regression-in-r-resulted-in-perfect-separation-hauck-donner-phenomenon

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239928/is-there-any-intuitive-explanation-of-why-logistic-regression-will-not-work-for

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/logistic-regression-model-does-not-converge?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you have correctly specified the GLM formula and the corresponding inputs (i.e., design matrix, link function etc...). The glm algorithm may not converge due to not enough iterations used in the iteratively re-weighted least squares (IRLS) algorithm.  Change  maxit=25 (Default) to maxit=100 in R.

Comment: that's possible, but it's rather unusual (in my experience at least) that glm fails to converge in 25 iterations but succeeds in 100 ...  (and doesn't explain the second warning message)