# Call 'glm' in R with categorical response variable

Tags: r, glm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting “algorithm did not converge” and “fitted prob numerically 0 or 1” warnings with glm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or)

I am trying to to fit glm using the following data with response variable `y1` as categorical. 
The code is giving me the following Warning message:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Sometimes, it does give me error

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

From the data it is evident that there is a clear relation between predictor and response variable.

1. Is the 'did not converge' error because of less number of data points?
2. `glm` is converting the response variable into factor as shown below. Is this normal?
3. Having an `x1` and `x2` value, how can I know the response?

   ```
     x1 = c(runif(10,50,100) , runif(10,101,150) )
     x2 = c(runif(10,1,50) , runif(10,51,100) )
     y1 = c(rep('n',10), rep('y',10)) 
     tmpData = data.frame(x1,x2,y1)
     tmpData
     str(tmpData)
     model <- glm(formula = 'y1~x1+x2', family=binomial(), na.action=na.omit, data=tmpData)
     summary(model) 

    >str(tmpData)
   'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
    $ x1: num  97.9 90.3 62.1 76 63.5 ...
    $ x2: num  18.6 49.4 21.2 47.7 24.8 ...
    $ y1: Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
   ```

Comment: have you googled this error message? Or google for "complete separation" ... or search on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or

Comment: This is a common problem in R with the glm, if you google a bit you will find different clues to look for. one of the reasons might be that your data is too perfect. Do a search in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ and you will find out many questions/answers for the same problem you have.

Comment: This is a repost of this closed question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47327/how-to-perform-glm-on-categorical-data-in-r