# More robust and faster polr for ordinal regression

Tags: r, regression, ordinal

Looking for a workaround, if there is a more robust and faster `polr` to fit for High Multi-dimensional data in an ordinal data context. (Similiar to those like `lm()` and `.lm.fit()`)

Example datasets: **https://filebin.net/e1qz05qy9qo6zpwa**

```
library(tictoc)
library(MASS)
custom_data <- read.csv(file.choose())
tic()
polr(LH_info ~ ., data = custom_data[,1:100])
toc() #0.61 seconds
```

**ADDED EDIT**: Issues found using current `polr` & `orm` methods:

Specifically Using this dataset for orm issues: https://filebin.net/hnpbkrw4gc9a5pn9

```
custom_data2 <- read.csv(file.choose())
custom_data2$OC_info <- factor(OC_custom$OC_info, order = TRUE,
                            levels=c("Extreme Low Open Close (<-40)","Common Lower Open Close (-40-0)", 
                                     "Common Higher Open Close (0-40)","Extreme High Open Close (>40)"))
test_model <- orm(OC_info ~ ., data = custom_data2[,1:101])
test_model2 <- orm(OC_info ~ ., data = custom_data2[,1:102])
```

Specifically Using this dataset for polr issues: https://filebin.net/hg7irb8al8pfs9sd

```
custom_data3 <- read.csv(file.choose())
custom_data3$OC_info <- factor(OC_custom$OC_info, order = TRUE,
                            levels=c("Extreme Low Open Close (<-40)","Common Lower Open Close (-40-0)", 
                                     "Common Higher Open Close (0-40)","Extreme High Open Close (>40)"))
test_model3 <- polr(OC_info ~ ., data = custom_data3)
```

1. `polr: Error in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite` --> Happens sometimes with some independent variables combination
2. `orm: Error in .local(x, ...) : Increase tmpmax` --> this always happen when try to model the dataset with more or equal of 100 independent variables

Comment: So you solved your problem by using less data? I have error message number 2. Tried so specify the ```tmpmax``` parameter as suggested [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-October/178523.html) but ```orm``` does not take ```tmpmax``` as an argument

Comment: @Simone sorry i havent been active at SO for a while, but actually.. i am not solving this issue using the `orm`, it failed modeling data with lots of variable in my case, since i can only think it has unexplored limitation, i did just use `clm` below to model an ordinal model.

Comment: not to worry. Same here. Thanks for the response. I fixed my problem by coding my ordinal scaled variables as integers (though not as numeric) Does clm also compute effect sizes easily? I have used ```polr``` and ````orm`` and just found the [brms package](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/). There seem to be many packages and functions out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `clm` function from the `ordinal` package or the `orm` function of the `rms` package to fit an ordinal regression. In both you could use `*.fit` options. Since you want to check the speed, here is a benchmark:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(MASS)
library(ordinal)
library(rms)

set.seed(7)
custom_data <- read.csv("dataset_example.csv")
custom_data$LH_info <- as.factor(custom_data$LH_info)
custom_data$LH_info <- as.factor(custom_data$LH_info)

m = microbenchmark(
  "polr" = {
    polr(LH_info ~ ., data = custom_data[,1:100])
  },
  "clm" = {
    clm(LH_info ~ ., data = custom_data[,1:100])
  }, 
  "orm" = {
    orm(LH_info ~ ., data = custom_data[,1:100])
  }, times = 100
)

m
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>  polr 174.6823 183.0839 194.1672 188.6606 195.7334 327.6748   100 a  
#>   clm 340.8700 354.7288 365.2914 360.8585 366.6671 485.0190   100   c
#>   orm 251.0034 261.5099 276.0913 266.3175 273.9440 405.5983   100  b
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(m)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Your `polr` option is already pretty fast.

---

More information about both functions:

- Great documenation about `ordinal` package: [Cumulative Link Models for Ordinal Regression with the R package ordinal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf)
- [docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/orm.html) of `orm` function (Ordinal Regression Model)

Comment: I have encountered some issues using `polr` and `orm` lately, though i believe no issues found yet when using clm (robust one) but according to your benchmark it is the slowest.. i will post some edit to address the issues, thanks for this

Comment: Hi @Jovan, I would highly recommend you check this post [polr(...) ordinal logistic regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839292/polr-ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r) and this post about why you are getting the error [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or).  These describe why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Quinten, I may need to take a while to understand most of it, but above issues actually can work with `clm` with some warning, does this mean the convergence error actually ruin every ordinal model effectiveness?

Comment: Nice benchmark about the speed. It does not say how to increase ```tmpmax``` (and neither does it say in [the reference manual link provided](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/orm.html) or address the other issue described. Wonder why a bounty was awarded to the answer?