# R vglm() error:　warning("fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred")

Tags: r, model, glm

I've been working out some vglm() model in R.
When I do this:

```
 fit <- vglm(label~.-index, family=multinomial, data=train)
```

I get an error as below.

> Error in if (min(ans) == 0 || max(ans) == 1) warning("fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have absolutely no idea what the matter is and how to fix it.

And I've tried this as well

```
fit <- glm(label~.-index, family=multinomial, data=train)
```

And I get another error which I can't figure out either. Thanks.

> Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Comment: Look up complete or quasi-complete separation in logistic regression. That should explain what the problem is (quick version: if a combination of predictors will result in perfect predictions then your probabilities should be either zero or one which corresponds to no variation. Multiple/logistic regression requires that probabilities are strictly between zero and one). You may need fewer predictors / more data

Comment: Also, check out the answer to this [question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or?rq=1)