# Ordinal Logistic Regression with mlr?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mlr

Is there any way to perform [Ordinal Logistic Regression (OLR)](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r/) with `mlr`?

One common implementation is the `polr` function from the `MASS` library.

See: 
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/multinomial-ordinal-logistic-regression/

or

[Ordinal Logistic Regression In R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416164/ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported at the moment and won't be added to mlr (though possibly to mlr3 at some point). You can [implement your own learner](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html) though.

Comment: You can try the mlr3ordinal package. It is still in early stages; contributions are always welcome.

Comment: mlr3ordinal sounds like exactly what I have been looking for. I wasn't aware of all these nice extension packages of mlr3. thanks!