# Error while imputing large dataframe using mice

Tags: r, r-mice

I have been trying to impute a data set using the `mice` package using the following code,

```
my_imp <- mice(train, m=5, method="pmm", maxit=50)
```

and I got this **error**:

```
iter imp variable
  *1   1  existence.expectancy.indexError in solve.default(xtx + diag(pen)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.96306e-17*
```

Here is a sample from my dataframe (`dput`). The error probably results from the `existence.expectancy.index` column.

```
structure(list(galactic.year = c(990025L, 990025L, 990025L, 990025L, 
990025L), galaxy = c("Large Magellanic Cloud (LMC)", "Camelopardalis B", 
"Virgo I", "UGC 8651 (DDO 181)", "Tucana Dwarf"), existence.expectancy.index = c(0.628656922579983, 
0.818082166933375, 0.659443179243005, 0.555861648365899, 0.991196351622249
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Please give me ideas on how to solve the error.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, could you share a sample of your data. Without that it will be very hard to find ot where the problem lies. Use can `dput()` or `dput(head())` if the data set is large. Please help us help you.

Comment: Hi, please read related Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832614/6574038 Possible duplicate.

Comment: @Afrikan_patriot What is different in your case that the provided error isolation approach there won't work?

Comment: @Afrikan_patriot Thanks for updating. However, when you use `dput` better don't change the output when providing it. I tried to fix that in an edit to your question. If you want to `dput` a subset of your data, use e.g. `dput(dtrain[1:30, ])`. Anyway, I tried out your code and data and wasn't able to reproduce your error. Also question of my last comment might still be open.

Comment: @jay.sf thank you for your advice and edit

Comment: @jay.sf i've got the solution.The problem with using mice for imputation here is the large number of unbalanced factor variables in this dataset. When these are turned into dummy variables there is a high probability that you will have one column a linear combination of another. Since the default imputation methods involve linear regression, this results in a X matrix that cannot be inverted.

One solution is to change the default imputation method to one that is not stochastic.

Comment: @Afrikan_patriot You may put an own answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using mice for imputation here is the large number of unbalanced factor variables in this dataset. When these are turned into dummy variables there is a high probability that you will have one column a linear combination of another. Since the default imputation methods involve linear regression, this results in a X matrix that cannot be inverted.

One solution is to change the default imputation method to one that is not stochastic.