# Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

Tags: r, model, regression

[banking_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdfTo.png)

```
library(MASS)
library(randomForest)

Bdata <- read.csv("banking_data.csv")
head(Bdata)
Bdata$y <- ifelse(Bdata$y == "y", 1, 0)
intercept_model<- glm(y~1,family = binomial("logit"),data=Bdata)
summary(intercept_model)
(exp(intercept_model$coefficients[1]))/(1+exp(intercept_model$coefficients[1]))
```

I tried to run this code but it shows Warning:

> glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

It shows :

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ 1, family = binomial("logit"), data = Bdata)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -26.57    1754.75  -0.015    0.988

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 0.0000e+00  on 41187  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.3896e-07  on 41187  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression gives a lot of advice

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on your data it will be hard to help you.

For general advise, see this [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or).

It could be because of the absence of two classes on your `y` data. Indeed, for instance :

```
y <- c(rep(1, 1000))
df <- data.frame(y = y)
reg <- glm(y ~ 1, data = df, family = binomial("logit"))
reg
```

Will return the same error. Did you check the balance of `y` with the function `table(df$y)` ?

Another solution is to increase the maximum of iteration :

```
reg <- glm(y ~ 1, data = df, family = binomial("logit"), maxit = 100)
reg
```

However this solution is not useful if you have only `no` inside your dataset.

Comment: I will put my data and other information now!

Comment: >      > Bdata$y <- ifelse(Bdata$y == "y", 1, 0)
    >         > intercept_model<- glm(y~1,family = binomial("logit"),data=Bdata)
    >       
    >     
    >          Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
    >             > summary(intercept_model)
    >         
    >         Call:
    >         glm(formula = y ~ 1, family = binomial("logit"), data = Bdata)
    >         
    >         Deviance Residuals: 
    >                Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
    >         -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06

Comment: >         Coefficients:
    >                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    >         (Intercept)   -26.57    1754.75  -0.015    0.988
    >         
    >         (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    >         
    >             Null deviance: 0.0000e+00  on 41187  degrees of freedom
    >         Residual deviance: 2.3896e-07  on 41187  degrees of freedom
    >         AIC: 2
    >         
    >         Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25

Comment: I put picture of my data in the post, please help me.

Comment: Could you see it know ?

Comment: age marital education occupation default housing contact quarter day duration campaign pdays previous poutcome y
1 56 married 0 0 no no telephone 0 1 261 1 999 0 nonexistent no

Comment: I advise you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The idea is to a sample of your data..

Comment: What does 100 lines of y will be enough? I didn`t get it .

Comment: sorry it doesn`t help me.........

Comment: Could you show the result of the table function ?

Comment: It still shows Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge, and still goes for 25 iterations.

Comment: If i try to use maxit = 100, it will show Warning message:
glm.fit: The fitting probability is calculated as a value of zero or one

Comment: Could just validate my help and try to use the link in advice and what I tell you to go through this problem ?