Warning message: In bgam.fit(G, mf, chunk.size, gp, scale, gamma, method = method, : algorithm did not converge
I am fitting this model:
m <- bam(f,
         data = d,
         family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
         select = TRUE,
         method = 'REML')

where f is y ~ s(t) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) + s(x4) + s(n1) + s(n2) + s(n3) + s(n4) + s(n5) + s(n6) and d is an augmented dataset in a discrete time-to-event setting with around 50,000 rows.
I am running a simulation study with 250 repetitions and this warning message appears for some of them:
Warning message:
In bgam.fit(G, mf, chunk.size, gp, scale, gamma, method = method,  :
  algorithm did not converge

I am not sure what is going on since m$converged is always TRUE. However, the estimation time for the replications with warning is much longer than without warning.
Does anyone have an idea what is going on? Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or

It's only a warning  ......  what were the estimates? And what happens when you simplify the model by removing terms,  or only using the untransformed variables,  or restrict the degrees of freedom in the smooths?

bam() probably has a maxit= argument. Check default value in documentation and set it to a higher value, e.g. maxit = 100. Another option is to store .Random.seed for each simulation which allows you to exactly reproduce the data from that round. Set seed using .Random.seed <- seed_from_sim_iteration.
